# Pandas group multiple rows by condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this.

```
FileName    XC    option1    option2    option3    option4
File1     sample1    A          B
File1     sample1                          C          D
File2     sample2    E          F
File2     sample2                          G          H
File2     sample2                          I          J
```

My expected output is something like this

```
FileName    XC    option1    option2    option3    option4
File1     sample1    A          B          C          D
File2     sample2    E          F          G          H
File2     sample2    E          F          I          J
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Basically I would like to merge the rows that are the same FileName and XC. As the output shows, there are 2 rows of File1 and sample1 with separated option1 option2 and option3 option4. I would like to merge the 4 options into same row.

If there are more than 2 rows like File2 sample2, eg 3rows, will merge them into 2 rows just like the output.

Comment: It is unclear to me

Comment: `.ffill` options 1 and 2, and then drop rows with NA in options 3 and 4?

Comment: Updated with detail question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A related question is here: [How to join two rows that have the same keys and complementary values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59774087/11670789).

If your option questions are quantitative, you can take the mean and then join to the Filename and XC columns.